# Drupal, views taxonomy filter fold up

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I'm pretty new to Drupal so I hope I'm attacking the problem right. I have a lot of products (content type) and each product has a product sort (taxonomy):

```
product sort1
  product sort1.1
  product sort1.2
     product sort1.2.1
     product sort1.2.2
product sort2
  product sort2.1
  product sort2.2
```

Now I have a view page with all product and I need a filter/menu in the left sidebar.

**Start Fase:**
All product are visible and the filter only shows: product1 & product2 (beneath each other)

**User clicks on product sort1**
The menu "folds open" and product sort1.1 en product sort1.2 are visible now. Both items are placed beneath product sort1

**User clicks on product sort1.2**
The menu "folds open" and product sort1.2.1 en product sort1.2.2 are visible now. Both items are placed beneath product sort1.2

Now we see this:

```
product sort1
  product sort1.1
  product sort1.2
     product sort1.2.1
     product sort1.2.2
product sort2
```

I have already tried a few modules:
(A page reload cannot happen, I use Ajax to avoid this)

- Simple hierarchical select (items come next to each other and there is some kind of menu reload, it flickers)
- client side hierarchical select (also items next to each other but no reload)
- simple exposed filter, select box (option elements are hard to hide or modify)

This is, I believe, a common filter effect used on many sites. But I can't find a module with this functionality.

Any ideas/modules/code that would help me with this problem?

Comment: I had big problems with menu made out of taxonomy terms on Drupal6. Problem is that for ordering (sub) items some 8bit number is used and if you have more than 256 (or that was 128, can't remember) you are doomed. Not sure is that fixed in D7, but check it out before you go deeper with this idea.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. With the modules I used it is possible but they are placed next to each instead of beneath each other (with the folding effect). So I think it must be possible to. I've been thinking about using jQuery to replace everything but it seems to quite complex and I think there must be a way to do this that I'm not seeing.

Comment: You could try [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) with hierarchical checkboxes and a bit of JS to fold/unfold parents.